# Error passing and getting Array values in Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

How I pass an array to another array?

I need to pass an array of double values but I don't know why it doesn't work. 
This is my code:

```
 private double[] Total_cost(){
double[] cost=new double[2];
.
.
.
cost[0]=tot_cost;
cost[1]=tot_cost2;
return cost;
}
```

Calling the method:

```
public void estr_grdcmpabs(){
      //
      double[] cost_grd=new double[2];
.
.
.
cost_grd= Total_cost();
 cst = String.valueOf(cost_grd[0]);
}
```

I get the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

How I convert the array value to a string to show in jframe?

Thanks.

Comment: `cost_grd[i]` is a `double` but `Total_cost()` returns a `double[]` (i.e. an array), so the assignment doesn't work. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I need to pass an array to an array.

Comment: A variable declared as `new double[1]` has only one element, and its index is 0. Indexing it at 1 will throw an exception.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the `cost` array is 2 but you have declared it of size 1. This will create `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
Replace the loop with this single statement so that the return type `double[]` matches

```
    cost_grd= Total_cost();
```

Comment: Ok, but now I get this error in code: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 2):

`Cost` is an array of doubles, while `cost_grd[i`] is just a double element in the cost_grad array of doubles
To solve either change the statement to

```
cost_grd[i]= Total_cost()[i];
```

Or remove the loop and change to:

```
cost_grd= Total_cost();
```

Comment: Another error, size is one while you are trying to put two elements, just change the size of cost_grd and cost to two